# Obtain prompt right away after "reset and clear" in GNOME Terminal

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome-terminal

I do run `reset` quite frequently while using GNOME Terminal. I've been trying to find a way to do (exactly) that using a shortcut. `Reset and Clear` (<kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>) "resets" the terminal in a similar fashion, but I have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get a prompt back.

Is there a way to get the behavior I'm describing?

> I've tried iTerm 2.x in macOS, and <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd> does exactly that, so I think there has to be a way to do this in GNOME Terminal as well, since this looks like a very basic workflow that many people might use on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `.bashrc`:

```
bind -x '"\C-k":reset xterm'
```

Source the file:

```
$ . .bashrc
```

Now when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> you should get the desired result.

Comment: Somehow, this doesn't change anything for me. I get the same behavior: I have to press `Enter` to get the prompt back.

Comment: @x80486 Take a look at [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93376/which-terminal-type-am-i-using) to see if some of the information there helps, I tried it with Zorin (gnome-terminal) and it worked... and now I'm on windows.

Comment: @x80486 Try with other letter than k, `'"\C-j"` for example.

Comment: OK, that did it! Looks like `Ctrl + k` is already bound (by default) so it takes precedence over this one.